# Dropdown content not showing when loading dynamic generated buttons

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, materialize

I have a question regarding MaterializeCSS.
I have an html table that has an option button that will display dynamic options generated based on the user.

This all works fine on the first run (when loading the page), yet when I reload the table contents (including the buttons) using AJAX the dropdown content won't show up anymore. Whilst the button click event still gets triggered.

I have tried multiple solutions yet none of these worked for my case.

Table (tbody content generated by foreach loop in php):

```
<table class="table highlight">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th class="center-align">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkAllUsers" class="checkToggle checkAllUsers"
               data-target="#boxUsers table tbody [type=checkbox]">
        <label for="checkAllUsers"></label>
    </th>
    <th>Username</th>
    <th class="hide-on-small-only">Email</th>
    <th style="text-align:center;" class="hide-on-small-only">Allowed</th>
    <th style="text-align:center;">Employee</th>
    <th>Action</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="usertablebody">
  <tr>
      <td class="center-align">
          <input type="checkbox" class="selectedUsers" name="u-1" id="u-1">
          <label for="u-1"></label>
      </td>
      <td>jGeluk</td>
      <td class="hide-on-small-only">jonah@example.com</td>
      <td style="text-align:center;">Yes</td>

      <td style="text-align:center;">No</td>
      <!-- ACTION BUTTON HERE -->
      <td>
          <div class="actions">
              <a class="dropdown-button showuseroptions btn-flat waves-effect" uid="1" href="#"
                 data-activates="showUserOptions">
                  <i class="large material-icons">more_vert</i>
              </a>
          </div>
      </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Dropdown content:

```
<ul id="showUserOptions" class="dropdown-content main-dropdown lighten-2">
    <li><a href="#">Loading...</a></li>
</ul>
```

Loading dynamic dropdown content (this runs without any problems on page load):

```
$("body").on('click', ".showuseroptions", function(event) {
var uid = $(this).attr('uid');
var btn = this;;
toggleLoader();
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: base_url + "ajax_admin_controller/fetch_user_options",
    dataType: 'text',
    data: {uid:uid},
    success: function(res) {
        if (res)
        {
            //"ul#showUserOptions"
            $("ul#showUserOptions").html(res);
        }
        toggleLoader();
    }
});


});
```

Refresh table function:

```
function refreshUserTable()
{
    toggleLoader();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: base_url + "ajax_admin_controller/fetch_users_table",
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(res) {
            if (res)
            {
                $(".usertablebody").html(res);
                toggleLoader();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Using

> $(this).dropdown();

as stated in the documentation doesn't have any effect.

I hope somebody can help me out.

Thanks,

Jonah

Answer (score 0):

call the dropdown after the ajax is completed and the html is appended

```
toggleLoader();
$('.showuseroptions').dropdown();
```

make sure you have a **unique id** for each dropdown

change

```
 dataType: 'html',
```

Comment: Tried that, doesnt work. I have multiple rows so I also tried to run a foreach loop for every element with the class: `showuseroptions`. This didn't work either.

Comment: you don't need a loop

Comment: I do have an unique id for every button but they activate the same dropdown content, but I don't for the dropdown content. Is this also required?

Comment: yes, how will jquery know what content is for what dropdown?

Comment: don't forget the `data-activates` to match the id

Comment: There is only 1 content element, the content of this gets loaded based on the user id (uid attribute) when the button is clicked. This works fine, except for when the `buttons` get dynamically loaded

Comment: con you provide a working jsfiddle, this should work

Comment: how do you initialize the dropdown? how do you get the content of the dorpdown based on uid?

Comment: Process typed out:
[1.] When I load the page the table gets created with php populated with data out of a database. (Everything works fine. dropdown opens)


[2.] I reload the table contents with AJAX calling `ajax_admin_controller/fetch_user_options`, this returns the same html as the static loaded one with php.


[3.] When I try to open the dropdown now, the button click event gets triggered, but the dropdown content won't open. Id's, name's, data-target identical as before (static loaded page with php)

Comment: so you have multiple buttons that are dynamically added, each button share a single dropdown body?

Comment: Yes, that's why I have the ajax to dynamically populate the content of that dropdown body. The content is based on the user id which gets passed using ajax. The `uid` attribute in the button element contains the user id

Comment: when you click `showuseroptions` you still have `<li><a href="#">Loading...</a></li>` after the ajax?

Comment: Yes, I do not load in `<li><a href="#">Loading...</a></li>`  via Ajax. This is still a static element.

Comment: you load into his parent `$("ul#showUserOptions").html(res);` assuming the ajax is successful yes?

Comment: Correct! That's true, but the parent element: `<ul id="showUserOptions" class="dropdown-content main-dropdown lighten-2"></ul>` is static. This does not get loaded by Ajax. That's why I think the problem lies with the buttons.

Comment: Yes, Well... The `.on('click', function(){});` is getting triggered (Checked that with alerts, show, hide, etc.), the ajax request is also made and successful. The only problem is that the dropdown body doesn't show up.

Comment: by **dropdown body doesn't show up** you mean that the content/html is there but the html isn't animated to show the list,yes?

Comment: Yes,  correct. Whilst before loading the buttons with ajax this problem did not occur

Comment: add `$('.showuseroptions').dropdown();` in `refreshUserTable()` after `$(".usertablebody").html(res);` and try again

Comment: That doesn't work, have tried multiple solutions stated on other posts/tickets. Yet none of them work for my situation